# Session Variables Not Being Stored

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have the following PHP code:

```
session_start(); 
$zip = $_GET['zip'];
$_SESSION['zip'] = $zip;
echo $_SESSION['zip']; //output is 98121, or whatever value I assigned
```

Then when I go to the next page using the following code:

```
 <div id="heading"><h2>What day and time would you like your stuff picked up?</h2></div>


<div class="nav_buttons">
            <button class="previous">Previous</button>
            <button class="next">Next</button>
</div><!--end nav_buttons--> 
<form action="/wordpress/junk-details" method="post">
<?php for($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++): ?>
    <div class="date_container" id="date_container_<?php echo $j;?>" >
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++): ?>
            <div class="day">
                <div class="date" id="">

                </div><!--end date--> 
            </div><!--end day--> 
        <?php endfor; ?>

    </div><!--end date_container--> 
<?php endfor; ?>
<div class="nav_buttons">
            <button class="next" id="goto_step2" type="image" value="next step"><span>Next Step: Details</span></button>
</div><!--end nav_buttons--> 
</form>
```

and I do a `var_dump($_SESSION)`, the value is `NULL`. I've checked my php.ini file, but didn't see anything out of the ordinary. I've searched other similar topics on SO, but none of those have helped.

Here is a list of links I've tried:

[PHP Session data not being saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved)

[PHP Session not Saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976930/php-session-not-saving)

[PHP Session Data Not Being Stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185448/php-session-data-not-being-stored)

Here are some details that might help:

> > I'm using PHP 5.5.3

I'm using a Mac OSX 10.9

I'm using the localhost as a server

This issue is on both Chrome and Firefox browsers

This is a wordpress site

I'm not sure what this could be. My sessions work when I use them on the back of my Wordpress plugin

Comment: Does the next page also contain `session_start();` ? It's not in there, from what I can tell.

Comment: No. It does not contain `session_start()`

Comment: Then that's your problem. If you want your session variables to appear on any other page, it must be included.

Comment: So every page has to have `session_start()`?

Comment: Well holly crap! It worked like a charm!!! Make that your answer and I'll upvote and accept! Thank you so much! I didn't realize I needed that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your session variables to appear on any other page, then `session_start();` must be included inside all your pages using **[sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)**.

---

**Footnotes**:

Should you happen in the future to get the following error message: `headers already sent`, you could add [`ob_start();`](http://www.php.net/ob_start) just above [`session_start();`](http://www.php.net/session_start)

Relevant links:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php
- http://www.php.net/session_start
- http://www.php.net/ob_start
- http://www.php.net/header

Comment: No biggie, hey it happened to me too way back when. Just sharing the wealth ;-) @Blaine

Comment: Lol... I know how that goes. I appreciate the speedy response and you sharing the wealth. I'm sure I'll be able to pass this along at some point.

Comment: You're very much welcome. I left a link in my answer for you to read up on. It contains a lot more information. @Blaine

Answer (score 0):

add `session_start();` on the top of your page in which you want to `set session` variable or `retrive session` variable value